# Using find_if on a vector of object

Tags: vector, c++

I have a vector of that looks like the following:

```
class Foo
{
    //whatever
};

class MyClass
{
    int myInt;
    vector<Foo> foo_v;
};
```

And let's say, in the `main`:

```
int main (void)
{
    vector<MyClass> myClass_v;
}
```

I want to find a object in `myClass_v` that has `myInt == bar`. I don't care about `foo_v`. I thought of using the `std::find_if` function:

```
std::find_if(myClass_v.begin(),myClass_v.end(),condition);
```

with

```
bool MyClass::condition(MyClass mc)
{
    if(mc.myInt==5)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

However the compiler says that `condition()` is missing arguments. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong? I thought that `std::find_if` would call `condition(*First)`, with `First` being a pointer to a `myClass` object.

Or is there another good way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

That's not how predicates work. You have to supply either a **free function** `bool Comparator(const MyClass & m) { ... }`, or build a **function object**, a class that overloads `operator()`:

```
struct MyClassComp
{
  explicit MyClassComp(int i) n(i) { }
  inline bool operator()(const MyClass & m) const { return m.myInt == n; }
private:
  int n;
};

std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), MyClassComp(5));
```

In C++0x:

```
std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
             [](const MyClass & m) -> bool { return m.myInt == 5; });
```

This captureless lambda is in fact equivalent to a free function. Here is a capturing version that mimics the predicate object:

```
const int n = find_me();
std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
             [n](const MyClass & m) -> bool { return m.myInt == n; });
```

Comment: "Predicate: This can either be a pointer to a function or an object whose class overloads operator()." What's wrong with a function pointer?

Comment: Nothing, but if you want to make the comparison value modifiable (my `n`), you need to store it somewhere, so a predicate object is the natural way to hold this extra information. If you only have one globally fixed selection rule, by all means use a free function `bool(const MyClass & m) { ... }`.

Comment: Oh OK, I just found `That's not how predicates work. You have to build a function object.` misleading.

Comment: Because you were passing an object to the algorithm, so I figured you're trying to build a predicate! :-) I'll update the answer, though!

Comment: Woops, sorry -- as a bonus, I'm adding capturing lambdas.

Comment: OP here, thanks a lot :) I'm wondering though, why isn't it possible to use a pointer to function if the function is defined in a class?

Comment: @Gramm: pointers-to-member and pointers-to-member-function are **not** function pointers. They're very different, incomparable type. Search on SO, you'll find thousands of questions regarding that.

Answer (score 4):

```
struct condition {
  bool operator()(const MyClass& mc) {
    return mc.myInt == 5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a functor or a regular function that is not part of MyClass, or with a static function inside MyClass - here's an example with non-member function (basically just removing the MyClass:: part of the condition definition):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
  //whatever
};

class MyClass
{
  public:
  int myInt;
  vector<Foo> foo_v;
};

bool condition(MyClass mc)
{
  if(mc.myInt==5)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}


int main (void)
{
  vector<MyClass> myClass_v;
  std::find_if(myClass_v.begin(),myClass_v.end(),condition);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides what **Kerrek SB**  wrote, you can also use the member function as a predicate.

Define it as `bool MyClass::condition() { return mc.myInt==5; }` - parameter is unnecessary since it already takes object as implicit parameter.

When using it, wrap `&MyClass::condition` (pointer to a member function) in `std::mem_fcn` from functional header.

```
std::find_if(myClass_v.begin(), myClass_v.end(), std::mem_fcn(&MyClass::condition));
```

A more verbose way to do it, is to use `std::function` or `std::bind`. Replace:

```
    std::mem_fcn(&MyClass::condition)
```

with

```
    std::function<bool (MyClass &)>(&MyClass::condition)    , or
    std::bind(&MyClass::condition, std::placeholders::_1).
```

If `MyClass_v` has been declared as `std::vector<MyClass *> myClass_v;`,

`std::function<bool (MyClass &)>(&MyClass::condition)` should be altered to: `std::function<bool (MyClass *)>(&MyClass::condition)`.
For `std::mem_fn` and `std::bind` - no changes are needed.

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Foo{};

struct MyClass
{
    int myInt;
    std::vector<Foo> foo_v;
    bool condition(){ return myInt==5; }
};

int main (void)
{
    std::vector<MyClass> myClass_v{ {1,{}}, {3,{}}, {5,{}}, {6,{}} };
    std::cout << std::find_if(myClass_v.begin(), myClass_v.end(), std::mem_fn(&MyClass::condition))->myInt << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```